# MFC inclusion in different flavors of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I learned via Wikipedia that Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express Edition does not ship with support for MFC projects.  Does anyone know if the Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1 distribution ships with MFC support ?  I imagine MFC versions for Win 7 are incomplete, but I only require basic/legacy MFC support for Win XP/Vista.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, VS2010 Beta 1 includes MFC.

(I checked via File / New / Project / Visual C++ and there's MFC in the list of available project types.)

But that doesn't necessarily mean that VS2010 Express will include it, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that final Express Edition of Visual Studio 2010 will be distributed without MFC since Express Edition is free. If you are planning to develop MFC projects you should buy at least Standard Edition of Visual Studio.